# Obtaining field types dynamically according to a field from another class (Using Scapy tool - Python)

Tags: python, class, network-protocols, layer, scapy

I'm wondering how to define field types for a class dynamically according to a field from another class ???
I mean how to define and link a field from a class to another class, example:

```
class TemplateRecord(Packet):
    name = "Template Record"
    fields_desc = [ ShortField("Type", 0),
                    ShortField("Length", 0) ]

    def extract_padding(self, s):
            return "", s


class DataRecord(Packet):
    name = "Data Record"
    fields_desc = [ ==> Here i would like something like this :

            "if Type == 0 from Class TemplateRecord:
                IPField("ipsrc", "0.0.0.0"),
            if Type == 1 from Class TemplateRecord
                IPField("ipdst", "0.0.0.0"),
            if Type == 2 from Class TemplateRecord
                                    ByteField("DstMask", 0),

            ....etc..." 

        ]
    def extract_padding(self, s):
            return "", s
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the closest feature that Scapy has to what you want is the Conditional Field.  The format is:

```
ConditionalField(XShortField("chksum",None),lambda pkt:pkt.chksumpresent==1)
```

Try using this in conjunction with Packet.underlayer.

Assuming that the layers are set up like TemplateRecord()/DataRecord()

```
ConditionalField(IPField("ipsrc", "0.0.0.0"), lambda pkt:pkt.underlayer.Type==0),
ConditionalField(IPField("ipdst", "0.0.0.0"), lambda pkt:pkt.underlayer.Type==1),
ConditionalField(ByteField("DstMask", 0), lambda pkt:pkt.underlayer.Type==2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the bind_layers function to add the conditional layer.
Steps:

1. Define main pkt template class (TemplateRecord)
2. Define sub pkt class (DataRecord1 for Type=1)
3. Use bind_layers to bind the 2 packet layers conditionally.

Syntax for your case would be:

```
bind_layers(TemplateRecord, DataRecordForType1, {'Type':1})
```